# httpClient.PostAsync returns "Method Not Allowed" (running in winform app)

Tags: c#, rest, httpclient, restsharp

I try to post to rest.

This is my code:

```
     string URL = "http://xxx.xxx.x.xx:8080/Name/NAME/";
     string urlParameters = "?key=T_PAPPS&value=sofsof";

     HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
     client.BaseAddress = new Uri(URL);

     client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
     new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));

     HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync(URL, new StringContent(urlParameters)).Result;
```

My app is WinForm application (not web).

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for advance.

(restsharp returns same error (and there I also didn't success to change to application/x-www-form-urlencoded from application/json))

Comment: Well probably it doesn't accepts POST requests.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using querystring parameters (ie ?key=value) you do not need to post. Try replacing your last line with:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(URL + urlParameters).Result;
```

You may also need to remove the final "/" in your URL string.